# Facebook invitation for friends

Tags: android, facebook

I am search how to in a my apps using a Facebook SDK. how to invited a friends for using a my apps or some event for invitations for example User1 invited you for play candy crash.

Please help me if you know about these. How to achieve in my apps using a Facebook.

Comment: It is described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Answer (score 0):

Have you check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial#requests of Facebook ?
Hope it will work for you

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putString("message", "Take this bomb to blast your way to victory!");

// Optionally provide a 'to' param to direct the request at a specific user
params.putString("to", "RECIPIENT_USER_ID");

// Give the action and object information
params.putString("action_type", "send");
params.putString("object_id", "YOUR_OBJECT_ID");  

WebDialog requestsDialog = (
        new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
            .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
```